# laptop charger oozing out green liquid?

Tags: laptop, usb, charger

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop for 3 years now. Recently I noticed the laptop charger head is letting out green liquid like this:

[image]

Also my mouse USB head plug is oozing out too.

After going through this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/x2zwe/has_anyone_had_a_charger_that_has_oozed_a_slimy/), I have a clear understanding regarding the cause of this. and I'm sure that my motherboard is clean and dry when I last cleaned it. Because that liquid is only oozing out when I squeeze the charger or mouse plug head. I believe I might been reckless to let a water into the cables head.

Everything works fine but my concern here is whether or not this slimy substance could cause any damage to the motherboard, charging, USB slots or cause any short circuit. Or maybe damage other cables that would go into the same slot. My battery doesn't have anything to do with it because it has been dead for more than a year now.

Comment: If your question is, "Is it bad to have mysterious green slime coming out of my laptop charger and USB ports" - yes.

Comment: Can we have a photo of the battery just to confirm there is no leakage from it? Also what do you mean by *"motherboard is clean and dry when I last cleaned it"*? How did you clean it?

Comment: as i mentioned the battery has been dead for like a year now and i've never used it since i lost hope for it. the leakage problem is more of a month old.
i opened my laptop to clean it couple of weeks ago, i checked the motherboard for strange moisture and it was dry. also checked the usb and charging slots to confirm the source of leaking was not from the inside.

Comment: the leaking is not from the actual port or "slot". it's from the cable that goes into the port.
so clearly i'm asking if it's bad to keep using it even if i covered the cable with some sort of insulator tap?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same with my laptop charger.
It is "the product of a reaction between decomposing plasticiser (a plasticiser is an oily liquid used in the manufacture of PVC compounds) and the copper conductors of PVC cables" (more details are here https://uk.prysmiangroup.com/media/news/green-goo). The reason is overheated cable or(and) cheap plastic.
You had better change the cable if you don't want to get dirty. This liquid is conductive and may short the circuit.
I suppose it is the same or similar depolymerizing process which goes in remote controllers. In remote controllers there is some oil liquid which appears from rubber silicone buttons as time goes by.